# Using variations of Parameter on Schrödinger equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

I'm stuck on this differential equation
\begin{cases}
y''(x,k)+(k^2-q(x))y(x,k)=0\\
y(0,k)=0,\quad y'(0,k)=1
\end{cases}
I try to integrate it directly, but it doesn't work. And there is a hint saying using variation of parameter.

In my mind, variation of parameter is feasible for $y''(x,k)+p(x)y(x,k)=0$, it seems not to be in this form or I just regard $(k^2-q(x))=p(x)$?

Comment: My fault, I want to say time-independent, not nonlinear. I'm out of spirits now....

Comment: It is exactly in that form, if you set $p(x)=k^2-q(x)$.

Comment: Okay, I will try it again.